# Python asyncio-motor doesn't work Asynchronously

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I tried below example to check whether it's Asyn or not. But it doesn't seems to be working. I used below code.

```
import asyncio
import time
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient


async def get_all_from_coll(col):
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient("localhost", 27017)
    db = client.project_matrix
    cursor = db[col].find()
    time.sleep(5)
    for document in await cursor.to_list(length=100):
        print(document)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print('001')
loop.run_until_complete(get_all_from_coll('users'))
print('002')
```

I'm getting the output in below order

```
>>>001
>>>{'_id': ObjectId('58d9b178d011b53743d44413'), 'username': 'test1', 'password': 'test', '__v': 0}
>>>{'_id': ObjectId('58d9b229d011b53743d44414'), 'username': 'test2', 'password': 'test', '__v': 0}
>>>002
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `time.sleep` is blocking. Use `asyncio.sleep` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for document in await cursor.to_list(length=100):
    # (wrong)
```

This will wait for `cursor.to_list()` to finish before starting the `for` loop. To run the `for` loop asynchronously (one-document-at-a-time), [you should use an `async for`](http://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html#async-for):

```
async for document in cursor.limit(100):
    # (ok)
```

---

But since your `print("002")` is executed *after* `loop.run_until_complete`, I don't see any problem with your output order.

Comment: If i did this in a language like javascript the result would be
    >>>001
    >>>002
    >>>{'_id': ObjectId('58d9b178d011b53743d44413'), 'username': 'test1', 'password': 'test', '__v': 0}
    >>>{'_id': ObjectId('58d9b229d011b53743d44414'), 'username': 'test2', 'password': 'test', '__v': 0}

i don't get it. What would be the difference if it's async if not the order?

Comment: @CoderS `loop.run_until_complete` means you are going to wait for the task to complete — your main "thread" is blocked on the `get_all_from_coll` "thread". So essentially your program becomes single-thread.

Comment: So there is no advantage of executing get_all_from_coll asynchronously?

Comment: @CoderS There is advantage if you are actually running multiple tasks concurrently (e.g. when invoked from an aiohttp request handler).

Answer (score 0):

In the above example it does not matter if `async for` is used or `await cursor.to_list()` is used. In either case there will be at least one block. In case await cursor is used you block only once, async for can have multiple blocks.